# How do you code in Powershell to get the latest date from an array?

Tags: powershell, date, compare

I have folders as follow:
- 10-17-17
- 10-18-17
- 10-19-17
- 10-20-17

I wanted to have PS to spit out that 10-20-17 is the latest folder located in my folder structure. I have no clue to go from here:

```
$path = "C:\Users\JJames\Desktop\Folder Structure Test"

$todaydate = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yy"

$arr = Get-ChildItem $path | 
       Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | 
       Foreach-Object {$_.Name}
```

I was able to get it spit out the names of each folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$path = "C:\temp"
$dirDate=New-Object DateTime

Get-ChildItem $path -Directory | %{

    if ([DateTime]::TryParseExact($_.Name, 
                                    "MM-dd-yy", 
                                    [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, 
                                    [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None,
                                    [ref] $dirDate)
       )
    {
        $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty "DateName" -Value $dirDate
        $_
    }

} | sort DateName -Descending | select -First 1
```

Comment: In the long run, if I wanted to change the date format to yyyy-MM-dd, will this still works? I tested and it's not working properly.

Comment: yes, try yyyy-MM-dd (format is in English not in french)

Comment: works perfectly. The first code before this one. I notice that if I only have 1 folder; it will not pick-up that folder. But this code works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to sort the object:

```
$path = "C:\Users\JJames\Desktop\Folder Structure Test"

$todaydate = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yy"

$folders = Get-ChildItem $path | 
    Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer}

$folders | Sort-Object { [DateTime]::Parse($_.Name)} -Descending
```

That's the short way, without error handling for date formats.

To get only the first item (sticking with super quick and easy)

```
 ($dateStrings | Sort{ [DateTime]::Parse($_.Name)} -Descending)[0]
```

Comment: Are you sure this is working? You doing a sort on strings and the date format is apparently `MM-dd-yy`. What if the day rolls over the month  (10-31-17 - 11-01-17) or over the year (12-31-17 - 01-01-18)?

Comment: @iRon You are correct. I knew I should have been casting that dates and now I am